# Reindexer configuration - Will it reindex new data for existing Indexes

Tags: performance, indexing, marklogic

MarkLogic - 9.0.8.2

We have around 5 indexes created which are used to search data (19M records) within MarkLogic

Now we want to add one more index, resource utilization will be depend on value defined in reindexer throttle (Large numbers mean work more harder reindexing)

As reindexing will take few hours/days to finish it up in production environment and should not have impact to performance on production environment, we followed (reindexer enable false during business hours) best practices suggested by MarkLogic.

[MarkLogic Best Practices for Reindexing](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/64/0/best-practice-for-adding-an-index-in-production)

[image]

[image]

Now my question is, with Reindexing disabled, will adding new data will be indexed for existing indexes which were created initially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reindexer setting applies only to the updating of existing data following configuration changes. With or without reindexing enabled, newly inserted data will be indexed with the configuration that is active during the insert.

In many cases this means that index changes should be applied in multiple steps: first, adding any new indexes required by the application, then deploying code with dependencies to those indexes after reindexing is complete, and finally removing any indexes made obsolete by the deployed code.